# Formula for rate of expansion of the universe vs distance?

Tags: observational-astronomy, observable-universe, dark-energy

How does the distance $r$ scale with the expansion of the universe?For example if $r_{o}$ is the distance between us and a galaxy and $V(r_{o})$ is the rate of expansion of the universe at that distance , what is $V(r_{0})$ equal to?

Comment: Define "distance". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measure

Comment: The coordinate distance , not the proper distance

Comment: "coordinate distance" isn't a term I recognise, can you define it?

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between [proper distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measure#Proper_distance) and the rate of change of proper distance is Hubble's law. So
$$ v(r_0) = H_0 r_0 \ .$$
Note that $H_0$ is the Hubble parameter at the present epoch. The Hubble parameter changes with time.

There are however different ways to define velocity and distance... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measure and these will have more complex relationships between them that depend on other cosmological parameters.